# Do fermionic creation/annihilation anticommutation relations fix the creation and annihilation operators?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, vacuum, fermions, anticommutator

If you define operators $a, a^\dagger$ which satisfy (e.g.) the relations $\{a,a\}=\{a^\dagger,a^\dagger\}=0$ and $\{a,a^\dagger\}=1$.

Will this uniquely define the operators such that $a |0\rangle \propto 0$, $a |1 \rangle \propto |0\rangle$, $a^\dagger |0\rangle \propto |1\rangle$, $a^\dagger |1\rangle \propto 0$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "uniquely define." Given the anticommutation relations that you wrote, we can construct an irreducible Hilbert-space representation that respects those commutation relations, and all such Hilbert-space representations are unitarily equivalent to each other. (This is obvious, because the Hilbert space is only two-dimensional.) But we don't normally consider just one $a,a^\dagger$ pair in isolation. It's usually in the context of a richer algebra, for which a two-dimensional Hilbert space is no longer sufficient.

Comment: Will it be uniquely defined if you provide *all* the respective anticommutators for a richer algebra?

Comment: In general, no: quantum field theories typically admit unitarily inequivalent Hilbert-space representations of the same algebra of field operators. A quick on-line search for the keywords "QFT unitarily inequivalent" turned up [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3239) and [this paper](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/341047?journalCode=phos) and [this paper](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/377411?journalCode=phos) and [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%27s_theorem). (Disclaimer: I haven't quality-checked any of these.)

Comment: I'm confused by exactly what implicit assumptions you need to make (probably about the occupation number representation), in order for the cannonical commutation relations + these asummptions to make the creation and annihilation operators behave as we'd expect

Comment: What do you mean by "behave as we'd expect"?

Comment: As in for a creation operator to change the state to a new state with an increased number of particles by 1, and the annihilation operator to change the state to a new state with a decreased number of particles by 1. Obviously operators that just satisfy the canonical commutaiton relations alone won't also do this (will they?), so what other implicit assumptions are we making?

Comment: Ah, I think I might see the issue. Just because operators happen to satisfy the (anti)commutation relations of creation/annihilation operators doesn't mean they have anything at all to do with *particles*. Determining which operators create/annihilate *particles* is a (usually) difficult dynamics problem, involving the Hamiltonian among other things. The names "creation/annihilation" operators are borrowed from the fact that their commutation relations are the same as those of operators that do create/annihilate particles in trivial models, but in general it's just a name.

Comment: It's kind of like if we always used the name "number of cube-faces" for the number $6$, even though the number $6$ is almost always used to represent something entirely different, not related at all to faces of cubes. Most operators $a$ that satisfy $\{a,a^\dagger\}=1$ and $\{a,a\}=0$ do *not* annihilate the vacuum state, even though we might still call $a$ an "annihilation operator." Determining which state is the vacuum state is again a (usually) difficult dynamics problem involving the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is helpful. It just seems weird to me that in problem sheets we always seem to be calculating commutators/anti-commutators with the intention of 'showing that these are creation/annihilation operators' when really their commutation/anitcommuation relations are necessary but not sufficient conditions?

Comment: I don't know if any of my comments here would qualify as an answer to the intent of your original question, but I'd be happy to move the comments into an answer instead of you like, or I can just plain delete them if they're no longer needed.